# Root space decomposition

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

What is the root system for the special unitary lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(p, q)$. Remind that these are matrices of the form 
$\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    X & Y \\
    \overline{Y}^t & Z \\
  \end{array}
\right)
$, where $\overline{X}^t=-X$, $\overline{Z}^t=-Z$, and $tr(X)+tr(Z)=0$. Also is there any reference regarding the action of the Lie group $SU(p, q)$ on complex projective space? Thanks.

Comment: This is discussed in Helgason's book on symmetric spaces.

Comment: I can not find anywhere in this book which answers my questions!

Comment: One can choose a Cartan to consist of diagonal imaginary matrices with trace $0$, then roots correspond to matrices with two nonzero entries that are off the diagonal in opposite positions that are conjugate or anti-conjugate to each other. You should be able to figure everything out from that.

Answer (score 8):

$\mathrm{SU}(p,q)$ is known as "type AIII", see e.g. [Goodman-Wallach](http://books.google.com/books?id=tbSX5VPE4PIC&pg=PA65), [Helgason](http://books.google.com/books?id=DWGvsa6bcuMC&pg=PA518), or [Knapp](http://books.google.com/books?id=U573NrppkA8C&pg=PA698) which may have the most details.

For its action on projective space and other flag manifolds a classic reference is [Wolf](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=251246). (If $pq\ne0$ then by Witt's theorem $\mathrm{SU}(p,q)$ has three orbits $P_+$, $P_-$, $P_0$ in projective space, consisting of the lines on which the defining hermitian form is positive, resp. negative, resp. zero. The former two are open while the latter one is closed.)